# Unable to install binutils on my ubuntu

Tags: binutils

I am trying to install binutils on my ubuntu:

1. Downloaded the package `binutils-2.22`
2. I run `./configure` & I get an error saying C compiler cannot create executables.
   Confused with the `config.log` really.
   Looks like it looking for some extra options..Can you please help?

The following error from `config.log` looks to be the problem:

> configure:4018: $? = 0
>
> configure:4007: gcc -v >&5
>
> Using built-in specs.
>
> COLLECT_GCC=gcc
>
> COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/lto-wrapper
>
> Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
>
> Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-4.6/README.Bugs --enable-
>   languages=c,c++,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr --program-suffix=-4.6 --enable-shared 
>   --enable-linker-build-id --with-system-zlib --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.6 --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --with-sysroot=/ --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --enable-gnu-unique-object --enable-plugin --enable-objc-gc --disable-werror --with-arch-32=i686 --with-tune=generic --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu
>
> Thread model: posix
>
> gcc version 4.6.3 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5)
>
> configure:4018: $? = 0
>
> configure:4007: gcc -V >&5
>
> gcc: error: unrecognized option '-V'
>
> gcc: fatal error: no input files
>
> compilation terminated.
>
> configure:4018: $? = 4
>
> configure:4007: gcc -qversion >&5
>
> gcc: error: unrecognized option '-qversion'
>
> gcc: fatal error: no input files
>
> compilation terminated.
>
> configure:4018: $? = 4
>
> configure:4038: checking for C compiler default output file name
>
> configure:4060: gcc    conftest.c  >&5
>
> /usr/local/bin/ld: this linker was not configured to use sysroots
>
> collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
>
> configure:4064: $? = 1
>
> configure:4101: result:
>
> configure: failed program was:
>
> | /* confdefs.h */

Answer (score 1):

why compile it manually?

```
    apt-get install binutils
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. That worked for me. BTW, we can append the specific version we want to download to package name & get it installed right?
For instance:--

apt-get install binutils2.x

Comment: ubuntu manage package dependencies, so old binutils may depend on other old packages, so ubuntu won't let you do that. (i'm not very familiar to ubuntu package management system, maybe it provide such method, but i don't know)